# can't seem to get an output from my class

Tags: python, class

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code and why I am not getting anything out. I also can't seem to figure out how to expand the rectangle. 
This is the instructions:
Create a method called `expand` that takes an offset value and returns a copy of the rectangle expanded with offset in all directions.

```
>>> r = Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)
>>> print(r)    
   Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)

>>> r1 = r.expand(offset=3) 
>>> print(r1)
   Rectangle(27, 37, 106, 116)
```

The original rectangle should not be modified.

```
>>> print(r)
   Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)
```

Negative values should return a shrunken rectangle.

```
>>> r2 = r.expand(-5)

>>> print(r2)
   Rectangle(35, 45, 90, 100)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, initx, inity, initw, inith):

        self.x = initx

        self.y = inity

        self.w = initw

        self.h = inith

    def __str__(self):
        return('Rectangle(' + str(self.x) + ',' + str(self.y) + ','
                            + str(self.w) + ',' + str(self.h)+')')
    def right(self):
        return self.x + self.w


    def top(self):
        return self.y + self.h


    def size(self):
        return '(' + self.w + ',' + self.h+ ')'

    def position(self):
        return '(' + self.x + ',' + self.y + ')'

    def area(self):
       return self.w * self.h

    def expand(self):
    # can't figure this part out


    r = Rectangle(5,10,50,100)
    r2 = Rectangle(5,10,50,100)
    r3 = Rectangle(3,5,10,20)
    r4 = Rectangle(12,10,72,35)
    r5 = Rectangle(5,7,10,6)
    r6 = Rectangle(1,2,3,4)


    print(r2)

    print(r3.right())

    print(r4.right())

    print(r5.top())

    print(r6.size())

    print(r6.position())

    print(r6.area())
```

Comment: try starting with `def expand(self,offset):`

Comment: If you don't want to modify the original rectangle, then you need to create a new one. How can you create a second rectangle, and what size/shape should it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def expand(self,expand):
    return Rectangle(self.x - expand, self.y - expand, self.w + 2*expand, 
                      self.h + 2*expand)
```

Or more generic against future overload....

```
def expand(self,expand):
    return type(self)(self.x - expand, self.y - expand, self.w + 2*expand, 
                      self.h + 2*expand)
```

And .... what about negative dimensions? Maybe is better fix it in constructor:

```
def __init__(self, initx, inity, initw, inith):
    self.x = initx
    self.y = inity
    self.w = max(0,initw)
    self.h = max(0,inith)
```

Finally we can talking about the subject of the question: *can't seem to get an output from my class*. Maybe is a indentation issue, I'll rewrite your script by my methods and by fixing indentation issue.

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, initx, inity, initw, inith):
        self.x = initx
        self.y = inity
        self.w = max(0,initw)
        self.h = max(0,inith)

    def __str__(self):
        return('Rectangle(' + str(self.x) + ',' + str(self.y) + ','
                            + str(self.w) + ',' + str(self.h)+')')
    def right(self):
        return self.x + self.w

    def top(self):
        return self.y + self.h

    def size(self):
        return '(' + self.w + ',' + self.h+ ')'

    def position(self):
        return '(' + self.x + ',' + self.y + ')'

    def area(self):
       return self.w * self.h

    def expand(self,expand):
       return type(self)(self.x - expand, self.y - expand, self.w + 2*expand, 
                      self.h + 2*expand)


r = Rectangle(5,10,50,100)
r2 = Rectangle(5,10,50,100)
r3 = Rectangle(3,5,10,20)
r4 = Rectangle(12,10,72,35)
r5 = Rectangle(5,7,10,6)
r6 = Rectangle(1,2,3,4)

print(r2)
print(r3.right())
print(r4.right())
print(r5.top())
print(r6.size())
print(r6.position())
print(r6.area())
```

Now it should work as you expect. In your code you had put variable definitions and `print` statements in the class definition.

Comment: thank you everyone for the help!, I am still not sure why my code has no errors but I'm still not getting anything to print?

Comment: @qaguy I've updated my answer. Now it should address your issue.

Comment: I want to add a method that covers if a point is inside or on the line or outside of the rectangle with a simple true or false answer not sure what to do, this is what I got so far. `def contains_point(self,contains_point):
        return (contains_point >= self.x or contains_point <= self.x + self.w
                and contains_point >= self.y or contains_point <= self.h)`

Comment: @qagui Maybe you should define it `def contains_point(self, x, y) ` and use x y to do the checks.  Otherwise you must define a point class or use a tuple

Comment: @qagui now you have the output and then I think you can accept the answer and continue by yourself to explore  the power of python :) have a nice trip.

Comment: I see what I did wrong I got it, thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: @qaguy find an acceptable answer means find an answer that you adopt as solution of your asked question. If you accept a question you should click on the *green V* near the arrows: by that click you will signal to the future readers that you found a solution of your issue and you found it in that answer. Without that click nobody will know if there is a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new object from the expand by using your rectangle points added by an offset.

```
def expand(self, offset):
    # can't figure this part out
    return type(self)(self.x - offset, self.y - offset
                self.w + offset, self.h + offset)
```